# Problema con reloj en Javascript + Carbon

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, carbon

Resulta que tengo el siguiente reloj, en javascript.

```js
function ActivaReloj(){
    var now = new Date();
    var hora = now.getHours();
    var minuto = now.getMinutes();
    var segundo = now.getSeconds();

    segundo = CheckZeros(segundo);
    minuto = CheckZeros(minuto);
    hora = CheckZeros(hora);

    if (hora >= 12){

        Imprime = hora + " "+":"+" "+minuto+" "+":"+" "+segundo+" "+"PM";
    }else if (hora <= 12){

         Imprime = hora + " "+":"+" "+minuto+" "+":"+" "+segundo+" "+"AM";
    }
        document.form_reloj.reloj.value = Imprime;
        setTimeout("ActivaReloj()",500);
    }

function CheckZeros(i){
        
    if (i < 10) {
            
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

```css
input{
width: 6cm; border-style: none; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6); color: white; border-radius: 10px; text-align: center; height: 1cm; font-size: 14pt; font-family: 'Roboto', 'Segoe UI'; font-weight: 300;}

body{
  background-color: #00A623;
}

form{
  margin-top: 5mm;
  margin-bottom: -10cm !important;
}
```

```html
<body onload="ActivaReloj()">
 <form name="form_reloj" id="clock">
   <input type="text" name="reloj" disabled="disabled">
 </form>
</body>
```

Pero como ese valor es **fácilmente modificable, modificando la hora del equipo**; lo que intento ahora es que el reloj obtenga la hora del **servidor**, el cual aunque cambie la hora del equipo el reloj **no debe cambiar.**

Lo intenté de la siguiente manera.

```
$now = Carbon\Carbon::now()->toTimeString();
return view('MyView', ['now'=>$now]);
```

Y Luego en el mismo `<input>` añadí la variable:

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="{{$now}}">
```

Pero, la hora no se actualiza automáticamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como desde `Laravel` obtiene la fecha con el formato `H:M:S`, podemos obtener estos valores para crear un objeto de la clase [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date), como no importa el día ni mes ni año podemos enviar cero en esos parámetros para el constructor.

Haremos uso de su función para añadir ceros a la izquierda, para la hora minutos y segundos, y por último utilizamos un operador ternario para asignar `AM` o `PM` según sea el caso.

**HTML *(blade)***

```
<form name="form_reloj" id="clock">
    <input type="text" id="reloj" disabled="disabled" value="{{$now}}">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
let inputHora = document.getElementById('reloj');
//obtenemos la hora, minuto y segundo
var nowServer = inputHora.value.split(':');
// construimos el objeto para aumentar los segundos
var dateNow = new Date(0,0,0,nowServer[0],nowServer[1],nowServer[2]);
// Cada 1 segundo, actualizamos los segundos
setInterval(() => {
    // incrementamos los segundos
    dateNow.setSeconds(dateNow.getSeconds() + 1);
    //asignamos los valores al input
    inputHora.value = checkZeros(dateNow.getHours())
         + ":" + checkZeros(dateNow.getMinutes()) + ":" 
         + checkZeros(dateNow.getSeconds() + "" +
         (dateNow.getHours() >= 12 ? ' PM' :  ' AM'));
}, 1000);

function checkZeros(i){
    if (i < 10) {   
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Asegurate de ponerle un id a tu input

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="{{$now}}" id="campo_hora" />

<script>
    var hora = document.querySelector('#campo_hora');
    var partes = hora.value.split(':');
    var ahora = new Date();
    ahora.setHours(partes[0]);
    ahora.setMinutes(partes[1]);
    ahora.setSeconds(partes[2]);

    //Cada 1 segundo actualizo el valor de la hora
    setInterval(function(){
        ahora.setSeconds(ahora.getSeconds() + 1);
        hora.value = ahora.getHours() + ":" + ahora.getMinutes() + ":" + ahora.getSeconds();
    }, 1000)
</script>
```